# Jest running entire test file when importing single named export

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jestjs

I have a test file with a number of tests and a utility function exported

```
export function createObjects(){
const numObjects = 100;
const objects = [];
 for (let i = 1; i < numObjects + 1; i++) {
        objects.push(i);
    }
return objects
}

describe('Test describe', () => {
  it('Test', () => {
})
})
```

I am trying to import the `createObjects` function in another test. However when I import the function like below in the second test

```
import {createObjects} from './TestOne'
```

It runs the entire test suite. Any idea why this happens?

I'm using jest 24.9.0

Comment: Why don't you separate the utility and the tests into two files?

Comment: Yeah that would work. I'm wondering why the entire test runs still.

Comment: Because when you import the function the whole file's loaded, which runs the call to describe that registers the tests.